# Convert JSON String to Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, function

I have this JSON string

```
{"ticker":{"high":736.45099,"low":681,"avg":708.725495,"vol":13038780.63684,"vol_cur":18382.55965,"last":726,"buy":726,"sell":724.5,"updated":1388242741,"server_time":1388242743}}
```

How can i get the "**last**" parameter after doing `json_decode()`?

Comment: `$jsonArray = json_decode('...', true)
echo $jsonArray['ticker']['last'];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php
$json='{"ticker":{"high":736.45099,"low":681,"avg":708.725495,"vol":13038780.63684,"vol_cur":18382.55965,"last":726,"buy":726,"sell":724.5,"updated":1388242741,"server_time":1388242743}}';
$json_arr=json_decode($json,true);
echo $json_arr['ticker']['server_time'];//"prints" 1388242743 which is the last param "server time"
```

Comment: Actually, the op asked about getting the parameter called `"last"`. Other than that, this answer is the right one.

Comment: I too thought in a similar way and hence [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816105/convert-json-string-to-array#comment31212710_20816105). +1 anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **json_decode** with parameters **json string** and **TRUE**.When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';     
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));    
?>
```

http://php.net/json_decode